# SignalR - Error during negotiation request

Tags: signalr

I have a successfully running signalr project where the work is done from an html page. I have taken the exact same html and pasted it into a .aspx page (with no master).

The signalr connection fails from the .aspx page giving error: Error during negotiation request

Has anyone any idea why this is. The code is **exactly** the same in the html and the .aspx page.

Have not included code here as it is working from the html page but if someone needs it please just ask.

Answer (score 0):

Gave up late last night, woke up and first thing I thought of was so blindingly obvious but will post here anyway in case it helps someone else - by moving to a .aspx page, a postback occurs when the input button is clicked (obviously)!. Anyway so by just adding return false; to the javascript button onclick function resolved the issue and am now able to connect to signalr.